# Easiest way to convert HttpResponseMessage to HttpActionResult outside of a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

Implementing `IExceptionHandler`, the result is expecting `IHttpActionResult`, but `createResponse` is returning `HttpResponseMessage`. I would like to simply create a response message from the request context. It does content negotiation and I would prefer using something that already exists, instead of creating a custom model implementing IHttpActionResult myself.

Controllers have access to helpers to easily make HttpResponseMessage into HttpActionResult, but there's nothing that I can find outside of the controller. What is my best option here?

```
var myCustomException = context.Exception as MyCustomException;

if (myCustomException != null)
{
   context.Result = context.Request.CreateResponse(myCustomException.StatusCode, 
                                                   myCustomException.Error);
   return;
}

context.Result = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
                                                new MyCustomError("Something went wrong"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the MSDN page will help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

you need a global error handler. here is core code, you will find details in MSDN page.

```
class OopsExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void HandleCore(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new TextPlainErrorResult
        {
            Request = context.ExceptionContext.Request,
            Content = "Oops! Sorry! Something went wrong." +
                      "Please contact support@contoso.com so we can try to fix it."
        };
    }

    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = 
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you should mention MVC version:

1. IHttpActionResult is replaced with IActionResult in ASP.NET Core 2:
2. ExceptionHandlerContext is in System.Web.Http, no longer exist too.
   here is details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.1#migrate-models-and-controllers

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. Ended up creating my own wrapper for the HttpResponseMessage. Was interested if there's a way to convert HttpResponseMessage to HttpActionResult without my own wrappers, something through .NET. How you can do it in ApiController.